# How can I create a cursor from xml nodes in a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm passing an XML document to my stored procedure as an argument. Then I'm trying to fill a cursor in order to loop through the elements of the XML. My question is how can I select every element of this XML Document and fill my cursor with them?

XML Document

```
<Authors>
    <Author_id>1</Author_id>
    <Author_id>2</Author_id>
</Authors>
```

Stored Procedure

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_Publication
    @authors xml
AS

    DECLARE @id int

    DECLARE authors_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT @authors.query('(/Authors/Author_id)') 

    open authors_cursor 

    FETCH NEXT FROM authors_cursor INTO @id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.nodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) and [`.value()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx):

```sql
DECLARE @authors XML = 
'<Authors>
    <Author_id>1</Author_id>
    <Author_id>2</Author_id>
</Authors>';

DECLARE @id INT;

DECLARE authors_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT n.c.value('.', 'INT') AS author_id
FROM @authors.nodes('/Authors/Author_id') AS n(c);

OPEN authors_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM authors_cursor INTO @id;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  PRINT @id;                                -- do whatever you need with @id
  FETCH NEXT FROM authors_cursor INTO @id;
END

CLOSE authors_cursor;
DEALLOCATE authors_cursor;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/418487)**</kbd>

How it works:

```sql
DECLARE authors_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT n.c.value('.', 'INT') AS author_id
FROM @authors.nodes('/Authors/Author_id') AS n(c);
```

1. `@authors.nodes('/Authors/Author_id')` get nodes based on `XQuery` and alias for derived table as `n` and `c` - for column
2. Use `n.c.value('.', 'INT') AS author_id` to get actual value of element

Comment: @VR46 Thanks :)  I am also preparing  demo

Comment: Thanks, seems great. Can you explain what n.c in n.c.value and n(c) mean?

Comment: @JimVer added explanation, simply use xml methods, add alias, get value from node